# Check if array contains string

Tags: java, arrays, file, search

Ok, I have this program that is supposed to store information about CDs that are available in txt file. The file stores the data in format 'artist[tab]album' on the same line. What I want to do, is to have user input search query, and the program return if the CD is in the database. So let's say we have Green Day[tab]American Idiot in .txt file on some line, and when users types in Green, the programs checks that file and returns true. But my problem is, my current algorithm requires the string to completely match, instead of partial. So the users needs to type Green Day[tab]American Idiot to get true on the query. How to fix it? Thanks. I am sure it is something I don't see as beginner.

This is the part of the program that manages the search in the array Artists, that contains all the data currently stored in the .txt file

```
 for (String e : artists){
        if(Arrays.asList(e).contains(search)){
         contains=true;   
        }
```

Comment: With your current data structure, it looks like there's not really an alternative to looping through the array and calling `.contains()` on each string. (This will be fine for small arrays, but may cause performance issues for larger ones.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating a list? You should use `artist.contains(search)` (yes, try to choose more relevant variable names). Also make sure you don't have `null` elements in the array or `search` is not `null` etc, but you can do something like:

```
for(String artist : artists) {
    if(artist.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()) {
        contains = true;
        // break; <- you may want to break here
    }
}
```

You may want to `toLowerCase()` both of them for case-insensitive search.

Comment: @TheLaw Thats because either `artists` is null (was not initialized and assigned an object) or your collection contains null. Check them.

Comment: Well I can't read minds so you will have to elaborate a bit. NPE means one of those variables is null. Double check which of them and why. Maybe `search` is null. Maybe one of your array elements is null. Maybe the array itself is null. Etc.

Comment: I create the array by calling a method and the number of elements in array is generated by this piece of code
    <code>for (int i=0; i < num; i++){
    artists[i] = bReader.readLine();
    }

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint before the loop and check the contents of the array and the value of `search`?

Comment: I did that, and both the variables are not empty and contain correct data, before reaching the NPE error.

Comment: Did you try the code above? Which bit throws a NPE?

Comment: Yes. For debugging reasons, I shortened the file to only two entries. For some reason, the first iteration goes through, but the second one throws the NPE. So probably issue with array dimensions being generated incorrectly, but I don't see anything wrong with my method that generates the array

Comment: Where exactly does the second iteration throw a NPE? Which line of code? Now that you found it, check which bit of that line is `null`. There really is no magic around it: a NPE is thrown. You know it's in the loop. You know it's the second iteration. You know how to use breakpoints. You should be able to at least find the line where the NPE is thrown.

Comment: That suggests to me the second element from `artists` is `null`.

Comment: I fixed it. Turns out, being inexperienced, I forgot to clean up after myself when modifying the method. At first, my method to calculate the size of array depended on number of elements - 1, because I used <= in the for loop to read from the file, and array starts at 0. Then I found better practice is to just use < for the loop, and I forgot to remove the subtraction from the elements. So my array was one element short. Now everything finally works as it should, thanks a lot. Also your suggested code works

Comment: Great. Here's a tip: learn very well all the debugging capabilities of your tool. Be a master at debugging. Literally go online and read about all the debugging features of your IDE and use them as much as you can. This is one of the most useful skills a developer can have. Your life will become much easier.